# How to add a storyboard view into a cell.contentView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"TNCNewsRow" bundle:nil];
    TNCNewsRowViewController *rowVC = (TNCNewsRowViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboard2"];
    NSArray *news = [_news objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    rowVC.news = news;
    cell.contentView  = rowVC;  // ??
    return cell;
}
```

I am trying to add a CollectionViewB into another CollectionViewA's cell.
But I am not sure how to do this programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[cell.contentView addSubview: rowVC.view];
```